# How do you specify an ACL policy when creating an S3 signed URL with Clojure's Amazonica?

Tags: amazon-s3, clojure, amazonica

I'm trying to make an upload have an ACL of `public-read`. The docs are super thin for [Amazonica](https://github.com/mcohen01/amazonica), and after hours of tinkering, I'm no closer to figuring out how to accomplish this goal. In short, I can't figure out how to get it to sign the header.

Server side, my code looks like this.

```
(s3/generate-presigned-url 
  creds
  {:bucket-name          "mybucket"
   :method               "PUT"
   :expires              10000
   :key                  "my-key"
   :cache-control        "max-age=31557600;"
   :request-parameters {:x-amz-acl "public-read"}
   })
```

Client side, I grab the URL that creates and do an XHR PUT request

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("PUT", signedUrl);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Cache-Control', 'max-age=31557600')
    xhr.onload = ...
    xhr.onerror = ...
xhr.send(file);
```

And this works perfectly, with the exception that it has the wrong ACL: "private" rather than "public"

Adding it client side is easy

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("PUT", signedUrl);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Cache-Control', 'max-age=31557600')
    xhr.setRequestHeader('x-amz-acl', 'public-read')
    xhr.onload = ...
    xhr.onerror = ...
xhr.send(file);
```

But the request of course fails due to `HeadersNotSigned`. I can't at all figure out how to add it server side so that they get signed. The `SignedHeaders` section never includes any additional parameters.

I've blindly tried all sorts of combos

```
(s3/generate-presigned-url 
  creds
  {:headers              {:x-amz-acl "public-read"}
   :x-amz-acl            "public-read"
   :metadata             {:x-amz-acl "public-read"}
   :signed-headers       {:x-amz-acl "public-read"}
   :amz-acl "public-read"
   :x-amz-signed-headers {:x-amz-acl "public-read"}
   :X-Amz-SignedHeaders ["x-amz-acl"]
   :request-parameters {:x-amz-acl "public-read"}
   })
```

How do you add an ACL policy to a signed url?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a direct answer to that, but a workaround for your consideration: making all objects in your s3 bucket default to public-read.

You can do this by adding this bucket policy to your bucket (replace `bucketnm` of course):

```
{
  "Id": "Policy1397632521960",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1397633323327",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucketnm/*",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "*"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```